# script to execute the eclipse PDE Tools > Build site

Tags: eclipse, build

i want to write a script to do the Build site of plugin Update site site.xml?
i could not find a way to do this?
i found very easy to build a plugin feature. I can automatically creat the ant file build.xml via eclipse but i could not find the same for the update site.xml

thank you all
stefania

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build an Eclipse plugin from Ant? You want to use the Ant4Eclipse external add-on for Ant. It lets you build the run-configurations you've made in Eclipse (right click>run as>...) from your .project file. You can download it [here](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) and there is a tutorial [here](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/81).

I attempted to do what you're asking at a previous job without using Ant4Eclipse, I don't remember how I got it working, but I do remember it being extremely difficult.

Edit: you can build an Eclipse update site from the command line, which can be run from Ant. There is some [possibly out of date] documentation [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Update_Site_Optimization), but I found you a sample from an [Apache projects build.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/uima/uimaj/trunk/uimaj-eclipse-update-site/build.xml?revision=824802&view=markup&pathrev=869029):

```
  <target name="build-site" depends="init">
    <copy todir="target/eclipse-update-site/web" preservelastmodified="true">
      <fileset dir="web"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="target/eclipse-update-site" file="index.html" preservelastmodified="true"/>
    <copy todir="target/eclipse-update-site" file="site.xml" preservelastmodified="true"/>

    <!-- copy all the features to the target -->
    <copy todir="target/eclipse-update-site/features" preservelastmodified="true" >
      <fileset dir="features"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Update_Site_Optimization -->
    <java jar="${eclipse.home}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true"
      maxmemory="256m">
      <arg line="-application org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer"/>
      <arg line="-digestBuilder -digestOutputDir=target/eclipse-update-site"/>
      <arg line="-siteXML=target/eclipse-update-site/site.xml"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way to create a launch config for the "Build All" menu entry of PDE.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just what I said in my comment: I want to automatically build an update site. I can create an Ant script for plugins and features but I'm missing something which can run those scripts and create a p2 update site from the result.

Comment: I haven't done that before, but I think I found a way. I've edited my original answer for you.

Comment: I'm not completely happy with the answer because it's for Eclipse 3.2 which is from 2006. There is more information here http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2009/05/migrating-eclipse-update-sites-to-p2.html but it's not really obvious how to get the same results as "Build All" from the menu in Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I wish I had access to my old Ant file, but if it helps running the Eclipse builder from the command line is referred to as a 'headless build'.

Comment: You might also be able to find  your answer by right clicking the project and hitting export. I don't have any projects with a site.xml on hand to test this, but maybe exporting an Ant file will do the trick?

Comment: There is no "Export Ant build file" option for update site projects. I only get that for feature and plugin projects. I guess I'll give Tycho a try instead.